# Azure active directory throwing "Not implemented" for api management disaster recovery

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-active-directory

I'm following this [api management disaster recovery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-disaster-recovery-backup-restore) guide on the microsoft docs, I've setup my active directory user and got the values from the config (as suggested) and then have  copied and pasted the code out of the example

```
var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxx");
var result = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", "xxx", new Uri("https://resource.com"), new PlatformParameters());
```

It seems that the suggested `new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto)` doesn't work as that object no longer required you to pass a parameter into the constructor, I get a `NotImplemented` exception:

```
System.NotImplementedException : The method or operation is not implemented.
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.PlatformParameters.GetCoreUIParent()
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Internal.Flows.AcquireTokenInteractiveHandler.CreateWebUIOrNull(IPlatformParameters parameters)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Internal.Flows.AcquireTokenInteractiveHandler..ctor(RequestData requestData, Uri redirectUri, IPlatformParameters platformParameters, UserIdentifier userId, String extraQueryParameters, String claims)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenCommonAsync(String resource, String clientId, Uri redirectUri, IPlatformParameters parameters, UserIdentifier userId, String extraQueryParameters, String claims)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(String resource, String clientId, Uri redirectUri, IPlatformParameters parameters)
```

I feel like the values for tenant, application id may be wrong so I'll decribe to the best of my ability where I got these values from:

Tenant Id:

- On the azure active directory option click the "app registrations" option
- Find and click "Endpoints"
- copy out the oauth endpoint
- take the guid that is in the url and paste it into the `var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{here}");`

Application Id

- On the azure active directory option click the "app registrations" option
- Find and click user who has the permissions required
- Click settings
- Click "properties" option in the list
- Copy out the "application id"
- paste it `var result = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", "{here}", new Uri("https://resource.com"), new PlatformParameters());`

Edit: Looking through the decompiled source I've actually found the cause of my problems it seems that it calls through to the platform parameters class to `GetCoreUiParent` which is simply not implemented:

```
public class PlatformParameters : IPlatformParameters
{
    internal CoreUIParent GetCoreUIParent()
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Edit 2 - I feel a bit of an idiot here but it seems that a new version of this nuget has been published as a preview it has a new version of the `PlatformParameters` class which has an implementation but requires more parameters than the example given, I feel I am on the right track

Thanks all

Comment: You can always post an answer to your own question. It could help other users from the future who stumble on the same (or similar) issue.

Comment: I haven't yet figured it out, but yes if I do figure it out I will try and answer my own question

Comment: I've seen this behavior **`NotImplementedException`** when using .NET Core 2.1. This code to acquire token should work perfectly with .NET Framework (*Full*) Console App. I also notice you've removed `PromptBehavior.Auto` from `new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto)` as it would also break for .NET Core. Guide you are referring tries to use `Delegated Permissions` and hence the code to prompt user for credentials.

Comment: Underlying issue being that .NET Core does not provide UI, so interactive flows aren't supported with .NET Core. GitHub thread with very similar code : https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/issues/885 I am still hesitating to add this as answer because you haven't mentioned that you're using .NET Core, but if that's the case and you confirm.. I'll try to elaborate in an answer.

Comment: Yes, I am using .Net core

Comment: ok in that case I suggest you try out with a .NET Framework console app and the same code from guide should work for you

Comment: @MarkDavies - can you please let us know how you achieved it? am also facing same issue using dotnet core 3.1

Comment: @SanjeeviSubramani if you look at the answer that I accepted, the really simple answer is that this is not possible right now, its been a while since I've looked at this but I remember having to basically do this another way on which I was doing it, probably best to look through the documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the steps in [Microsoft Docs Guide you are referring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-disaster-recovery-backup-restore#configuring-your-app) register a `Native` application with Azure AD and then make use of `Delegated Permissions`. So there is code to prompt user for signing in and entering their credentials.

Now this code will work perfectly with a .NET Framework (*Full*) Console Application but not with .NET Core.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant id}");
        var result = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", "{application id}", new Uri("{redirect uri}"), new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto)).Result;
```

Underlying issue for .NET Core is that it does not provide UI capabilities, so interactive flows aren't really supported with .NET Core.

This is also the reason you had to remove `PromptBehavior.Auto` from `new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto)` as this would break for .NET Core.

You can find more information in the references mentioned below:

- Here is a thread on GitHub with code very similar to yours [Interactive authentication in .net core 2.0 console application on windows](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/issues/885)

  [image]
- Documentation for ADAL on GitHub. See it clearly says `Except for .NET Core, which does not provide any user interaction`

  [image]

---

On a side note, I know [.NET Core 3.0](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.0) is coming up with [support for Windows Desktop Applications](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-3-and-support-for-windows-desktop-applications/), but it's all still in preview.

In future interactive flow should work with .NET Core 3.0 and [MSAL.NET](https://aka.ms/msal-net) (different than [ADAL.NET](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki)).

More details here: [ADAL does not properly support .NET Core 3](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/issues/1510)

[image]